# Await A Task In VB Framework 3.5

Tags: .net, vb.net, frameworks

I was working with framework 4.5 in VB and I have a task function:

`Private Async Function StartDownloads() As Task`

And in the function I have a line of code:

`Await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(New System.Uri(fileurl), Path.GetTempPath() & "\" & name)`

But the issue is when I downgrade to framework 3.5 or lower, `Task` and `Await` are not added yet in 3.5, but are in 4.5... Is there another way to make the function a task and use the await function to wait for the line of code to finish before the code continues?

If anyone can please help, let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Task asynchronous pattern, also known as just *TAP*, and `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace were added in .NET 4.0. That is, the answer is **no, you can't use *TAP* in earlier versions of .NET Framework than 4.0**.

Comment: Yes I understand, but is there a way to do the same thing without `Task asynchronous`, but using a different function or something of that sort? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @TymeBomb While the other answerer gave you the hint of AsyncBridge, I wouldn't recommend you this because check that the post is from 2012 and .NET has evolved a lot since 2012........ If you want to work with earlier framework versions you might need to go with old async pattern BeginInvoke/EndInvoke, async result...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer that project is inactive right now, but open source projects never die as you get the code. Your advice on Begin/End* is not quite good, as they are gone in .NET Core in favor of pure async/await. Anyway the ultimate solution is to get rid of .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

There can be significant limitations, but AsyncBridge should help you in some scenarios,

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/04/18/asyncbridge-write-async-code-for-net-3-5/